# new to docker,wonder how to read docker's source code?

Tags: docker

Don't know if it's ok to post here, new to docker and using it to build a simple app engine, so i want to look inside docker to see what's going on.

forked the source code,but you know, it's a little harder for me to read it directly,because have no idea on the whole map of it's execution flow,so i want to ask for help,how to read the source code of docker?whether anyone had write some post to explain on it?

background info: know how to use docker ,familary with it's commands

thanks for your help:)

Comment: thanks everyone, now we using docker for two years(based on mesos), moving to k8s next two months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker is written in [go language](http://golang.org/). The two fundamental principles you need to understand are the cgroup and namespacing capabilities of the Linux kernel.

Have a look at the [docker's github source code repository](https://github.com/docker/docker) and [contributing to docker guide](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).
Also, you can check this [book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=4xQKBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=extending+docker&source=bl&ots=wv2K8A2aJR&sig=TqUUlRZW8i6EbZ6rPoi6oZWVezw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uWfhU-a2N8S68gW_p4LQAQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=extending%20docker&f=false), it explains how to extend docker.

For the source code, you can start from [docker.go file](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docker/docker.go).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to existing comments and useful information contained in them, you could also refer to [Docker Code Walk](https://wxdublin.gitbooks.io/docker-code-walk/content/client.html) resource.